# p5.js repetition of the same function

Tags: javascript, class, repeat, p5.js

I am learning p5.js and I don't quite understand how to repeat my function on the y-axis so that the lines appeared on top of the other. I understand that I would need to make a class object but all that I succeeded to do was to freeze the editor XD. Could you help me figure out how to make my function repeat itself with different Y starting point?

```
let walkers = []; // creation of an array 
this.xoff = 0; //changed to go outside of the walker class 
this.yoff = 0; //changed to go outside of the walker class
this.x = 0;
y = 200;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(250);
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  //mix array and class
    walkers[i] = new walker(y);
  }

}


function draw() {
  for (i = 0; i < walkers.length; i++) {  // consider the array lenght
    walker[i].acceleration(); // call the class and it's function
    walker[i].velocity();
    walker[i].update();
    walker[i].display();
  }

}

class walker {
  constructor(y) {  //divide the class in multiple function 
    this.y = y
  }


  acceleration() {
    this.accX = 0.1;
    this.accY = 0.1;
    this.px = this.x;
    this.py = this.y;
  }

  velocity() {
    this.velocityY = random(-20, 20);
    this.velocityX = 5;
  }

  update() {
    this.x = this.x + this.accX + this.velocityX * noise(this.xoff);
    this.y = this.y + this.accY + this.velocityY * noise(this.yoff);
  }

  display() {
    for (this.y < 200; this.y > 400; this.y + 20) {
      line(this.x, this.y, this.px, this.py);
    }
    this.xoff = this.xoff + 1;
    this.yoff = this.yoff + 100;
    this.px = this.x;
    this.py = this.y;
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually the variables `xoff`, `yoff`, ... are initialized in every frame. Every time when `walker` is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with how your code behaves.

Here are a few issues:

- `walkers` it the array used,: e.g.`walkers[i].acceleration();`, not  `walker[i].acceleration();` (same hold true for the rest of the calls)
- initialize variables if you plan to use them (otherwise using math operators update() will end up with [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN): e.g. `this.x, this.xoff, this.yoff`, etc.
- it's unclear what motion behaviour you're after with position, velocity, acceleration, perlin noise, etc. (which btw are updated with strange increments ( `this.yoff = this.yoff + 100;`))

The code mostly freezes because of this:

```
for (this.y < 200; this.y > 400; this.y + 20)
```

It's unclear what you're trying to do there: `this.y < 200; this.y > 400` makes me think you were going for an `if` condition to only draw lines between 200-400 px on Y axis, however `this.y + 20` makes me think you want to increment y for some reason ?

It's also unclear why `x,xoff,yoff` moved out the `walker` class ?
There may be some understanding around classes, instances and the `this` keyword.
As per JS naming convention, [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) names should be title case.

I can tell you've put a bit of effort trying to build a more complex sketch, however it will won't be helpful for you to add complexity unless you understand all the parts of your code. This is where mastering the fundamentals pays off.

I recommend:

- going back to pen/paper sketching to work out your idea until it's clearer
- thinking of how you will achieve that by breaking complex tasks into smaller steps
- writing basic test sketches for each step/component

Finally, bring one component at a time into a main program, testing again as components interact with another. Be sure to check out [Kevin Workman's How to Program guide](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program).

FWIW, here's a modified version of your code, with a tweak to set the initial y position of each Walker on top of each other:

```js
let walkers = []; // creation of an array 

y = 200;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(250);
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  //mix array and class
    // incrementally add 10 pixels to y so the initially lines start on top of each other
    walkers[i] = new Walker(y + (i * 10));
  }
}


function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < walkers.length; i++) {  // consider the array length
    // walkers, not walker
    walkers[i].acceleration(); // call the class and it's function
    walkers[i].velocity();
    walkers[i].update();
    walkers[i].display();
  }

}

class Walker {
  constructor(y) {  //divide the class in multiple function 
    this.y = y;
    // remember to init all variables you plan to use
    this.xoff = 0; //changed to go back inside of the walker class 
    this.yoff = 0; //changed to go back inside of the walker class
    this.x = 0;
  }

  acceleration() {
    this.accX = 0.1;
    this.accY = 0.1;
    this.px = this.x;
    this.py = this.y;
  }

  velocity() {
    this.velocityY = random(-20, 20);
    this.velocityX = 5;
  }

  update() {
    this.x = this.x + this.accX + this.velocityX * noise(this.xoff);
    this.y = this.y + this.accY + this.velocityY * noise(this.yoff);
  }

  display() {
    // what were you trying ?
    //for (this.y < 200; this.y > 400; this.y + 20) {
      line(this.x, this.y, this.px, this.py);
  //}
    this.xoff = this.xoff + 1;
    this.yoff = this.yoff + 1;
    this.px = this.x;
    this.py = this.y;
    // reset x, y to 0
    if(this.x > width){
      this.x = 0;
    }
    if(this.y > height){
      this.y = 0;
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for quite a while! For the weird loops, I think I was trying too many things to find out what was wrong that I did not know what was wrong anymore! You are totally right, I need to know more about the fundamental. I wanted to explore with class object since I noticed I was avoiding it. Finally, I ended up going into a complex project! This random walker quite challenged me! And thanks to you I feel more comfortable continuing my experimentation with class object.

Comment: I saw you went to goldsmiths!!! I am taking online classes in p5js to get ready for my semester in computational arts at goldsmiths!!! How did you like your experience there?

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be easier to do it using a class. Make different functions inside the class which are responsible for update, movement, etc. You can make a display function too in which you can set the y co-ordinate using a For loop. In that way, it will become very easy to keep changing the y co-ordinate.

If you want to display multiple lines at once, do all of the above and also use an array to store the y co-ordinates and then display them in the For loop.

Do let me know if you need help with the actual code.

Comment: Hi M.Wadia. Thank you so much for your comment! I have tried different things and got inspired by Daniel Shiffman's bubbles example. But, for some reason, p5js does not recognize the function I create in the walker class. I could definitely use your experience with the changes I made.

Comment: I have found a few issues, but George has explained a lot more in his answer. Do refer to his suggestion as it has addressed all the issues and the code gives the desired output.